# Is there a word for a "diverse amount of knowledge"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "a diverse amount of knowledge"?

I would be used in a sentence like this:

> Trying to give a **diverse amount of knowledge** covering many fields and genres of text.

Comment: 'A good general knowledge' is the term I'd use, Adrik. In English, 'general knowledge' is a fixed (widely known, used, and understood) expression. See for example the definition given in [CambridgeDictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/general-knowledge).

Comment: Just a nitpick but "Trying to give a diverse amount of knowledge covering many fields and genres of text." isn't a sentence because it doesn't have a finite verb. And it's not very clear exactly what you want - there are various words that might be possible like compendium, encyclopedia, anthology, catalog, treasury, oracle, compilation, etc, but without knowing what you've considered, what you're writing, or what your criteria are, it's very hard to suggest something.

Comment: What exactly is *diverse amount of knowledge* supposed to mean? On the face of it, it seems to mean that one amount of knowledge is different from another amount of knowledge, which is, in turn different from yet another amount of knowledge, etc., but it is not easy to imagine the circumstances under which one would want to say something like that. What is *diverse amount of* supposed to add to *knowledge covering many fields* in your example?

Comment: To be more clear than jsw29 "diverse amount" is syntactically incorrect. "Diverse" is not an appropriate adjective for amount. A small amount of knowledge can be diverse (or not), or a large amount can be concentrated (and therefore not diverse). Or not.

Comment: Diversity of knowledge doesn’t really come in “amounts.”

Comment: It is noteworthy that those who attempted to answer the question have ignored the fact that *diverse* in the OP's phrase qualifies *amounts*, and have spontaneously assumed that the diversity is the diversity of the kinds of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the depth of coverage is not too great, then [*broad overview*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/broad-overview) might be appropriate.

> Trying to give a broad overview covering many fields and genres of text.

This tends to imply a summary or survey of a range of topics suitable as an introduction to the field of discourse.

Answer (score 0):

If the knowledge is high-level, then

> OED
>
> **B. polymath** adj..
>
> **Of or relating to a polymath; characterized by extensive or varied learning.**
>
> 1997   J. Satinover Cracking Bible Code vii. 94   *Alberti was but the first in a rapid succession of brilliant polymath Renaissance scholars.*

(less common/rare)

> **polymathic**, adj.
>
> **Of or relating to extensive or varied learning;** = polymath adj.
>
> 1994   N.Y. Rev. Bks. 26 May 55 (advt.)    *Unsociable individual, male, polymathic, 47, desires correspondence with an intelligent, thoughtful, feminine (not feminist) woman.*

Answer (score 0):

How about

- Diverse insights
- multiple perspectives
- broad and robust coverage/discussion
- in-depth and diverse